# Keeping a list of websocket connections in Tornado

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I figured to keep track of multiple websocket connections I have to store the WebSocket Handler objects in a list. But I have multiple handlers - one for each WS URI (endpoint). Lets say my project has three end points - A, B, C

```
ws://www.example.com/A
ws://www.example.com/B
ws://www.example.com/C
```

So to handle connections for each of these, I have three handlers. So I am puzzled about where to create the list to store the handler objects to be used later.

My code before adding the list is --

```
class WSHandlerA(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'


class WSHandlerB(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'

class WSHandlerC(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/A', WSHandlerA),
    (r'/B', WSHandlerB),
    (r'/C', WSHandlerC),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

So where do I create this list and make sure it's visible to all the objects created? I am new to python as well and so having a little trouble wrapping my head around it.

I also realize I could probably use just one URI (endpoint) and send the multiple commands as part of the message itself. But then I don't want to turn WebSocket into a binary protocol. Given that we have URIs I should be using them.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Rod Hyde - This is not a Websocket question as such if you see. Its more of a python question. I already know how to handle connections, just did not know how to put it in python. So I don't agree that its a dup (the title might be close)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you want to do *with* the handlers, but you could easily make them accessible in three lists:

```
# Global variables.
a_handlers = []
b_handlers = []
c_handlers = []
```

`WSHandlerA.open()` does `a_handlers.append(self)`, and `WSHandlerB.open()` does `b_handlers.append(self)`, and so on. `WSHandlerA.on_close()` does `a_handlers.remove(self)`.

If you want to do something with all A handlers:

```
for handler in a_handlers:
    handler.write_message("message on A")
```

To do something with all handlers:

```
for handler in a_handlers + b_handlers + c_handlers:
    # do something....
    pass
```

By the way, if you use a Python `set()` instead of a list for each set of handlers it'll be a little better. With sets instead of lists, use `add` and `discard` instead of `append` and `remove`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My main issue I realize now was with the usage of lists. Since they allow duplicates I needed code to check for duplicates for each operation, which is what I could see where to add. set() solves that problem and covers everything I need. Thanks!

Comment: Short and simple. Thank you!